# Exporting contours with elevation from QGIS to CARLSON SURVEY/INTELLICAD

Tags: qgis-3, dxf

Using QGIS 3.20, the GRASS plugin did not work properly, I am unsure why, and I have tried following along with some YouTube videos but have not been able to export elevations along with the exported .dxf file.

Is there any procedure to do so?

Comment: in QGIS when exporting DXF you need to set the geomtery type (point, linestring) then you need to select the 'include z-dimension'

Comment: Thank you, I also have to adjust CAD setting to allow for height!